# Certificate installation

Tags: installation, x509certificate

I have a setup file (setup.msi) which is digitally signed and if I try to install the setup in a machine will the certificate install by itself or should I install the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to install the certificate.

The certificate that was used to sign your setup.msi is stored inside setup.msi. Of course, it does not contain its private key so that no one will be able to use it to sign something else. The certificate stored inside MSI is used to verify whether it's trusted or not, and to verify the integrity of package.